# Draw Polyline Google Maps API3 using checkbox, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I include Google Maps in my project and I want to draw a Polyline on the map between two markers, but with a checkbox. everything works great without function and checkbox.
This is code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function placePolyline(chkb)
            {
                if(chkb.cheked==true)
                    {
                var MarkerArray= [];
                for(var i=0;i<arrayLatitude.length;i++)
                    {
                        var lokacijaMarkera = new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLatitude[i],arrayLongitude[i]);
                        MarkerArray.push(lokacijaMarkera);
                    }
                var polyOptions = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: MarkerArray,
                    map: map
                  });

                  polyLine = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
                  polyLine.setMap(map); 
                //  
                    }
                else{
                    polyLine.setMap(null);
                }

            }

    </script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkb" ">
<input type="button" value="Drew polyline" onclick="placePolyline(chkb)"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property of a [checkbox](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_checkbox.asp) is "checked" not cheked